# Style (only) decimal of ordered list

Tags: css, styling, html-lists

Is there anyway to bold the decimals in an ordered list using CSS only? The CMS we are using is spitting out li's with no nested p/span/header tag so I can't bold the li and reset the nested tag...

Any ideas?

thanks

Comment: Please post (a representative sample of) your HTML and CSS.

Comment: If your CMS already relies on jQuery, you can do it with a single line: `$('#myList li').wrapInner('<span>');`, with CSS: `li { font-weight: bold }` and `li span { font-weight: normal }`. See: http://jsfiddle.net/SSzuh/ Though, it would probably make more sense just to edit your server-side output code to include the `span` tag.

Comment: thanks for your suggestions. Solution below worked for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you may use :first-line pseudo-element for the li, like

```
li {
  font-weight: bold;
}
li:first-line {
  font-weight: normal;
}
```

It works for the latest versions of modern browsers, except IE.

For IE you need to use scripting to add nested tag for the li's

Comment: This works fine as long as your li is no more than one line ;)

Comment: correct, I haven't found other way to do what you want without scripting or changing generated HTML from server side. See here for all available CSS options: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html